# Laravel Godady returning 404 on routes

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I always use Forge for my apps but a client insisted on keeping his GoDaddy. As I hate GoDaddy, I am stuck with a routing issue. THe home page works buy my APIs are getting 404.

Structure

Public_Html

```
  ->htaccess
  ->index.php
  ->css
  ->js
  ->images
  ->laravel/
      ->all core stuff
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I know its probably some .htaccess thing since the Laravel structure has changed. Anyone know?????

Comment: Change your `RewriteRule` as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1`

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP} off

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^https://www.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.111
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
```